# iOS 13: app crash on start by Flurry Unity SDK

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, flurry, flurry-analytics

After updating to Xcode 11, app crash at start in iOS 13 Unity.

I am using Flurry Unity SDK version 1.5.0.

Error in Xcode:

```
2019-09-25 10:54:30.835351+0530 myschool001[1558:434572] -[NSURLResponse allHeaderFields]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2810dca20
2019-09-25 10:54:30.836057+0530 myschool001[1558:434567] -[NSURLResponse allHeaderFields]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281123560
Assertion failed: (writer->uncaught_exception.has_exception == false), function Flurryplcrash_log_writer_set_exception, file /Users/xyz/code/plcrashreporter/Source/PLCrashLogWriter.m, line 474.
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a crash is occurring in your app due to 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'.

I was not able to reproduce this with the Flurry plugin in a clean project or by intentionally causing an 'unrecognized selector' crash (using Xcode 11 and iOS 13).

Can you send us a bare bones copy of your Unity project that reproduces the error? Please send it to support@flurry.com along with a link to this Stackoverflow thread.

Also this may be a conflict between Unity's crash reporting and Flurry's so you could try turning off Flurry crash reporting.

```
void Start()
{
    // Initialize Flurry once.
    new Flurry.Builder()
              .WithCrashReporting(false)
              .WithLogEnabled(true)
              .WithLogLevel(Flurry.LogLevel.LogVERBOSE)
              .Build(FLURRY_API_KEY);
```